# Triggering a AWS Lambda from a form post

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've created a small AWS Lambda that sends an email using SES. I'm looking to hookup a contact us form from a static website to this lambda.

Is it possible to have the contact us form post directly to a url of the lambda? I'm not using a server side framework and would really like to avoid it, what are my options? Is there client side Javascript way to invoke the lambda?

Comment: Adding cloudfront as a proxy in order to use the same origin is another alternative to CORS: https://www.codeengine.com/articles/process-form-aws-api-gateway-lambda/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Wrote a blog post about this.](http://moonsault.co/2015/06/23/using-aws-lambda-app.html)

This is totally doable. It's a matter of using AWS Cognito to call that function.

1. You have your lambda function in place. Grand.
2. Create a new Cognito group.
3. Give the unauth'ed Cognito group permissions to execute the lambda function.
4. Wire it all up in the browser. I have some example code here…
   https://github.com/chadbaudoin/lambda-twilio/blob/master/index.html

The “hard” part is making sure that the IAM settings for the Cognito group and the Lambda function are all set up correctly. I used this tutorial pretty heavily, but used cognito to execute so I wasn't exposing keys.

http://lg.io/2015/05/16/the-future-is-now-and-its-using-aws-lambda.html

Comment: Did you mean to leave this line in your code?  // AWS.config.update({
  //   region: 'us-east-1',
  //   accessKeyId: 'something',
  //   secretAccessKey: 'somethingelsethatlooksimportant'
  // });

Comment: @greg_diesel it seems to be an invalid access key, so that's good.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. I didn't use a Cognito group, looks like a AWS user does the trick as well